# detecting Integers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, integer

I'm trying to use Haskell (which I am completely new too) and Every time I attempt to compile this using ghci I get `Not in scope: 'isNumber'`, what am I doing wrong?

```
digits :: [a] -> Bool
digits a = digits a True


digits1 :: [a] -> Bool -> Bool
digits1 [] False      = False           
digits1 [] True       = True            
digits1 (l:ls) True   = digits ls isNumber l
digits1 (l:ls) False  = False
```

Comment: You might like `digits = all isNumber`.

Comment: ok well I tried this code :
digits :: String -> Bool
digits = all isNumber
but whenever I try to execute it using digits: "String" I get 'not in scope' if String is letters and 'No instance for (Num String)' if it is number (1123) etc. What is causeing this?

Comment: Don't forget to enclose the argument in double-quotes if you want a `String` literal, as in `digits "foo"` or `digits "123"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get that error message because `isNumber` is defined in the `Data.Char` module, which you didn't import it. Importing it will fix that error.

That's not your only problem though. One other problem is that `digits ls isNumber l` is calling `digits` with four arguments, but you've defined `digits` to only take one argument.

Similarly the call `digits a True` calls `digits` with two arguments - same problem. You probably meant to write `digits1 a True` here, as `digits1` does take two arguments.

Lastly both `digits` and `digits1` are defined to take arbitrary lists as arguments, but you seem to want to call `isNumber` on the list's elements. Since `isNumber` is a function that only works on `Char`s - not arbitrary values - you should probably take a list of `Char`s (i.e. a `String`) instead.